# C++ class const member intialization within constructor body

Tags: c++, class, constructor, constants, member

I have a problem with initialization of a const class member.
I have to do many calculations before initialization of the const member, so I can't use this syntax

```
Class::Class(int value) : value(value) {}
```

I wish to initialize the member in the constructor body, for example:

```
Class::Class(int value) {
  if (Function1(value)) {
    this->value = value;
    Function2(&this->value);
  }
  else
    this->value = value * 2;
}
```

Is it possible?
Hope for your help!

Comment: You could write a helper function with a signature like `static preprocess(int value)` and then the member-initialization syntax would look like `Class::Class(int value) : value(preprocess(value)) { }`. Although I'm skeptical about the `Function2` stuff, which doesn't appear to involve initializing the class and might make designing such a function more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect all the calculation into a static calculation function.

```
struct Class {
    static int calcValue(int value) {
        if (Function1(value) {
            Function2(&value);
            return value;
        }
        return value * 2;
    }

    Class(int val)
        : value(calcValue(val))
    {}
};
```

Comment: You have passed a reference of the static methods function argument, into Function2, not the same as passing a reference to the class member, although it is `const` according to OP, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Mansoor I assume `Function2` alters `value` before we return it. I don't think it stores the pointer. If that's not the case, OP can let us know.

Comment: Not sure about that, in that case, you will have mutated the value before setting the class member, whereas, in OP's example, he first sets the member variable then passes it into `Function2`.

Comment: @Mansoor the end result should be the same, right? Mutating the value before setting or mutating the member variable afterwards

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the q. carefully, if the member is const, then `Function2` must accept a const ref, so it can't mutate anything.