# Set const class members inside constructor after reading config file

Tags: c++

Given the following class:

```
class A {
  public:
    const int x;
    const int y;
}
```

I want to initialize the constant variables in the constructor of the class, but *after* reading a configuration file. So like this:

```
A::A(filesystem::path config){
  // read and process config into c
  x = c.x;
  y = c.y;
}
```

This does not work because C++ wants constant class members to be set like this:

```
A::A(filesystem::path config): x{foo}, y{bar} {}
```

How would one implement the above behavior, so first read the config file and then set the const variables?

One option is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057969/c-class-const-member-intialization-within-constructor-body), so handle reading the config file in an extra function but this would need to be called twice in this case or N times if N is the number of variables to be read. And it feels messy. What is the proper approach?

Comment: Why do those class members need to be const ?

Comment: @TheEagle They will (and should) never be changed. I assumed that such variables should be const.

Comment: If your config changes them, they're not `const`. Maybe you need to think of having a `const A` instead of `const` properties.

Comment: @tadman they are supposed to be const after the constructor? How would you then implement that behavior?

Comment: I really think you're confusing what `const` is intended to be used for.

Comment: @tadman having a const A seems like a good idea. Need to think about that.

Comment: @tadman An instance of the class is supposed to represent a specific configuration (read from a configuration or elsewhere).

Comment: I think you'll find it a lot more convenient to have things mutable by default, but pass around `const` references to this data where no mutation will happen. For example, your config reader has read/write access, while components that just need to read the config are passed `const A&` always. If you're accessing through a `const` reference, the properties are considered `const`.

Comment: Get rid of the `const`, make them private, and add public getters.  That way you class can be assignable.

Comment: @tadman this is a bad design. If you allow people to do something, they will do it eventually and cause problems. It is a lot better to hide mutability and expose public getters only, as sugested by NathanOliver.

Comment: Most of the time you do want to make things `const` to prevent simple screw-ups, but `const` member variables tend to suck.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess that seems safest. But it adds a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: @cmosig btw, why can't you process data outside of the constructor and pass processed values to a basic constructor? You can even wrap it in a static method. Especially since your constructor suggests that it does side-effects (file i/o), which is not necessarily good.

Comment: @cmosig That's a known feature of C++ ;) That said getters are quite simple and you can easily create a macro to reduce the amount of code you have to write like `#define MAKE_GETTER(var) auto get_##var() { return var; }` [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/718cee74634e220e)

Comment: Do you know what delegating constructors are, and how to use them?

Comment: @freakish I could do that, and I guess this static function would then read the config file and return an instance of A. I would like to avoid it though because there are already other constructors of A which initialize A using other methods.

Comment: @NathanOliver Guess I will have a feature-full class. Thanks for the macro, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this issue by putting your config in same class *before* other variables and initializing from it. After construction you can "reset" it to free memory.
Here is conceptual example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
    struct Config {
        Config(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
        int a;
        int b;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<Config> tmp;
public:
    const int x = tmp->a;
    const int y = tmp->b;
    A(const std::string& path) : tmp(read_config(path)) {
        tmp.reset();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Config> read_config(const std::string& path) {
        return std::make_unique<Config>(1, 2);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a("");
    std::cout << a.x << " , " << a.y << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [Builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern):

```
class Builder{
public:
    //the parameters
    int _a, _b;

    Builder(string filename){
        // read _a and _b from config file
    }
    YourClass getObject(){
        return YourClass(_a, _b)
    }
}

class YourClass{
public:
    YourClass(int _a, int _b):a(_a), b(_b){}
private:
    const int _a;
    const int _b;
}
```

And then you can instantiate your class object in one line:

```
YourClass c = Builder(filename).getObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from the rule of the order of initialization of class members and base classes. Namely, the base classes parts initialize in their order in inheritance list and then the members initialize in order of their declaration.

So, the first option would be:

```
class vec {
public:
    vec() { /* read and process config*/ }
    int x, y;
};

class A {
    vec c;
public:
    const int x;
    const int y;

public:
    A() : x(c.x), y(c.y) {}
};
```

and this will give the necessary separation between config and your type.

Or with the base class:

```
struct vec {
    int x, y;
};

class Config {
protected:
    vec c;
public:
    Config() { /* read and process config */ }
};

class A : Config {
public:
    const int x;
    const int y;

    A() : x(c.x), y(c.y) {}
};
```

which gives even better separation of the classes.